# Trig modeling - population

Tags: trigonometry, mathematical-modeling

A population drops from 200,000 in 1950 to 76,000 in 1996, and has risen since then. Taking into account that the population follows a sinusoidal cycle affected by environmental conditions and predation, and the population will reach its previous high again, what is a possible sinusoidal formula to describe the population as a function of time in years?

So far, I have
let t=0 in 1950
A(t)= 200,000(r)^t

I'm not sure how to factor in the sinusoidal cycle part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the maximum value is $200$ (in thousands), and the minimum is $76$ (in thousands). Then we want an amplitude of $\frac{200-76}{2}$. We really want a period of $2\cdot46$ (max/min occurs at half the period), and so the coefficient of $t$ set as $\frac{2 \pi}{2 \cdot 46}$ satisfies this. A cosine function will work well here. What we have so far is
$$\frac{(200 - 76)}{2}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{2\cdot46} t\right).$$
Now we need to add a constant, because this thing has a peak at $\frac{200-76}{2}=62$. We want it to peak at $200$, and so we add $138$, and end with
$$f(t)=\frac{(200 - 76)}{2}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{2\cdot46} t\right)+138.$$
Here is a plot of that effect:

[image]

Comment: thank you! That makes sense. Is there any way to tell in how many years will the population reach 200 (thousand) again?

Comment: Absolutely. You can solve $f(t)=200$ for $t$. The thing is, it reaches that value every $2n \cdot 46$ years from year $t=0$, and so there is really nothing to solve. At $92$ years from year $0$ the model reaches peak again. :)

Comment: Ah, that was very straightforward and obvious. Thank you so much for the clarity in your explanation and all of your help :)

Comment: My pleasure :).

Comment: Excuse me but I have one last question. If there were a separate population that rises when this population is under 100,000 then what percentage of the time would that separate population be higher?

Comment: Add this as a separate question (new post), and you can refer to this post for that new question. This way you will be able to clearly write out this new question with good detail and get a proper answer. I am sensing in this new question that the solution involves a superposition of waves, but again, this is a question that should be posed anew with greater detail and precision. I will be sure to peek after you post it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

[image: Hint]

So if the period of the $y=cos({2x\pi\over t})$ is $t$, what do you need the period of your function to be? How far horizontally do you need to shift your function? How far vertically? How much do you need to scale it?